# How to nicely decouple paging and heap (dynamic memory management) functionalities in OS development?

Tags: operating-system, kernel, paging, heap-memory

### Background

I am following [James Molly's OS tutorial](http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/) to implement a toy operating system, of which I found the paging and heap [code](http://www.jamesmolloy.co.uk/tutorial_html/the_heap.tar.gz) very involved because of their interdependence. For example, paging uses `kmalloc` provided by the heap because it needs to **dynamically allocate** space for the page table data structures and must have **the virtual address**. This is done in the following function call in `paging.c`:

```
dir->tables[table_idx] = (page_table_t*)kmalloc_ap(sizeof(page_table_t), &tmp);
```

Meanwhile, the heap relies on paging to allocate physical frames when it needs to grow, which can be seen in `kheap.c`:

```
alloc_frame( get_page(heap->start_address+i, 1, kernel_directory), (heap->supervisor)?1:0, (heap->readonly)?0:1);
```

They are tightly coupled together within the memory management module, like the following:

```
             other modules
          ^        ^       ^
          |        |       |
          v        v       v
+-----------------------------------------+
|             Memory Management           |
|                                         |
|     +------------------+                |
|     | paging           |                |
|     |            +-----+------------+   |
|     |            |     |            |   |
|     +------------+-----+            |   |
|                  |          heap    |   |
|                  +------------------+   |
+-----------------------------------------+
```

### Question

I am wondering if it is likely to completely decouple paging and the heap. I expect it to be possible because conceptually, I think

1. Paging can be thought as a address mapping/translation mechanism (probably plus physical frame allocation??).
2. The heap is about dynamic memory management.

They seem pretty self-contained respectively. Can they be implemented in a decoupled fashion with only unidirectional dependency, for example like the stacking TCP/IP protocols?

Comment: If you want to collect *suggestions*, it is **too broad** for Stack Overflow (or *primary opinion-base*). If you have an idea about implement something - why simply do not **try** it? You write your toy OS from scratch, so almost everything is possible to implement.

Comment: I was asking for better ideas. And I feel the question is already specific enough that contains both the concept and the details (in the referenced code).

Comment: "referenced code" is actually an archive with tens of source files. If you want us to review some part of your code, provide it in the question post (**as text**). We won't review your project in total. As I said above, "better ideas" request in your case is not suited for Stack Overflow as *primary opinion-base*. My idea as an example: you may  use own heap for paging, so it won't depend on general-purpose heap for dynamic memory management.

Comment: Being better or not is surely opinion-based, but being decoupled, which I was asking for, is relatively objective. I also don't think a dedicated heap does could resolve the inter-dependency as long as the heap needs growing and shrinking dynamically. But I do see your point. This is probably not a very good question to ask here because it is indeed too conceptual and vauge. But if I expand on the details there would be too much code and technicalities. I will try to be more concrete. Please let me know if there are other ways to improve the question.